# Activating shading for a .stl based environment in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, gazebo-worlds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I built a simple rolling landscape terrain using the sculpt tool in Blender and exported this as STL. Using the terrain in a launch file works ok, but I can't figure out how to activate proper shading so visualization looks nice. I tried many of the available gazebo materials (PR2/Grey1, Gazebo/PioneerBody, Gazebo/White, Gazebo/GrassFloor) but all those resulted in a monochromatic landscape.

The relevant parts of the .world file are:

```
  <rendering:ogre>
    <ambient>0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5</ambient>
    <sky>
      <material>Gazebo/CloudySky</material>
    </sky>
    <grid>false</grid>
    <maxUpdateRate>10.</maxUpdateRate>
    <!--<shadowTechnique>none</shadowTechnique>-->
    <shadows>true</shadows>
  </rendering:ogre>
  
   <model:physical name="landscape">
   <xyz>0 0 0</xyz> 
   <rpy>0 0 0</rpy>
   <static>true</static>
   <body:trimesh name="landscape_body">
     <geom:trimesh name="landscape_geom">
       <scale>1.0 1.0 1.0</scale>
       <mesh>rolling_landscape_120m.stl</mesh>
       <visual>
         <scale>1.0 1.0 1.0</scale>
         <mesh>rolling_landscape_120m.stl</mesh>
     <genTexCoord>true</genTexCoord>
     <material>Gazebo/GrassFloor</material>
       </visual>
     </geom:trimesh>
       </body:trimesh>
  </model:physical>
```

Screenshot (using PR2/Grey1 material, Gazebo/GrassFloor looks the same, only green)

[image description http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/6132/unshadedlandscapegazebo.png](http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/6132/unshadedlandscapegazebo.png)

The monochromatic visualization obviously makes judging distances of terrain features impossible. Shadows for the quadrotor UAV work (but shading apparently does not work).

The .stl, world and launch file are also available in the [hector_gazebo_worlds](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_gazebo_worlds) package and can be started using

```
roslaunch hector_gazebo_worlds rolling_landscape_120m.launch
```

/edit: So I found out that terrain as well as quadrotor do not receive illumination at all, but if I spawn spheres or other objects via the gazebo toolbar, those receive proper illumination.

Update: I tried playing around with materials and found that there is a difference like night and day (literally ;) ) between built-in primitives and mesh files.

Consider this extract from a URDF file:

```
  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1.316" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
      <inertia ixx="0.0128" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
      iyy="0.0128" iyz="0.0" 
        izz="0.0218" />
      </inertial>
      
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>        
           <cylinder radius="0.4" length="0.2"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="DarkGrey" >
          <color rgba="0.3 0.3 0.3 1"/>
        </material>
      </visual>
      
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://hector_quadrotor_urdf/meshes/quadrotor/quadrotor_base.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </c![image description](http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/6112/gazebodisk.png)ollision>
      
    </link>
    
    <gazebo reference="base_link">
      <material>Gazebo/White</material>
      <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
    </gazebo>
```

Looks like this in gazebo:
[image: image description]

The cylinder apparently receives correct illumination.

If I now use the following line instead of the cylinder (everything else stays the same, most notably the material!)

```
 <mesh filename="package://hector_quadrotor_urdf/meshes/quadrotor/quadrotor_base.stl"/>
```

the same scene looks like this:
[image: image description]

Can someone explain this? The mesh looks perfectly fine in Blender, Meshlab etc., so I doubt the normals are wrong. It seems very wrong that materials show such differences between being used for built-in primitives and external meshes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12704/activating-shading-for-a-.stl-based-environment-in-gazebo/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2012-01-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I define my own materials and set them to image files that are non-monochromatic. It helps a bit with this problem. Take a look at the Gazebo.material file in `simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/share/gazebo/Media/materials/scripts` for an example. In your package, you can set it up to export materials to Gazebo (because you don't want to modify the simulator_gazebo folder if you didn't install from source). You can find that tutorial [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/GazeboConfiguration).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-01-20**:
Sure, but what's the material used by the spawnable objects? My guess from looking at them would be "Gazebo/White", but this doesn't work for my meshes.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-20**:
I gave you the link to the material files. That's where all materials are located.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-01-20**:
Oh, and when I spawn shapes like spheres, those get illuminated correctly. So I'll have a look at their material. /edit: Of which I don't know where to find it.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-01-20**:
Ok, when setting ambient really really low, everything is very dark as expected. Added light sources produce shadows for the UAV, but otherwise do not illuminate the scene. There has to be something stupid I'm doing wrong :)

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-01-20**:
Yes :) I'll try setting ambient lower and playing around with the light sources once more

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-20**:
Have you tried increasing the intensity of your point light source?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-01-20**:
The GrassFloor material actually is non-monochromatic and should work when setting genTexCoord to true, right? Doesn't work for me (in this scenario). While having a texture is better than nothing, I'd really like to have normal-based lighting, like when viewing the mesh in Blender, Meshlab etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the exact same problem today. STL files exported by Blender somehow do not receive shading when spawned inside Gazebo. Tried reversing/recalculating normals to no avail. Just import the STL into Meshlab and export it without doing anything. This enabled the shading for the mesh.

---

Originally posted by [equilibrium](https://answers.ros.org/users/3618/equilibrium/) with karma: 51 on 2012-11-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GuiRitter](https://answers.ros.org/users/27461/guiritter/) on 2016-07-11**:
Worked for me, thanks! I thought it was the "Unify Duplicated Vertices" option that appears when an STL is loaded in MeshLab that fixes it, but I tested without and it's not.